# Priority queue works with vectors but not lists

Tags: list, vector, stl, priority-queue

I am tightening up some rendering code and instead of storing all my renderable objects in a plain ol vector I decided to use a priority queue (this way things like transparency can be automatically prioritized correctly).  I cannot get it to work with a list as the underlying data structure however.  I have tried it using both a functor and by overloading the < operator.  It complains about:

```
Error   8   error C2676: binary '-' : 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2425    1   ObjLoaded
Error   4   error C2676: binary '-' : 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2331    1   ObjLoaded
Error   7   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2425    1   ObjLoaded
Error   3   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2331    1   ObjLoaded
Error   6   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2425    1   ObjLoaded
Error   2   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2331    1   ObjLoaded
Error   5   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2425    1   ObjLoaded
Error   1   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<IRenderable *>>>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2331    1   ObjLoaded
```

This is how I am declaring the priority queue:

```
priority_queue<IRenderable*, list<IRenderable*>> m_renderlist;
```

with the overloaded < operator.  If I make one simple change, everything runs:

```
priority_queue<IRenderable*, vector<IRenderable*>> m_renderlist;
```

Any Idea why might be happening here?  For completeness, here is my  overload and functor:

```
bool IRenderable::operator<(const IRenderable* comp)
{
    if (this->GetPriority() < comp->GetPriority())
        return true;
    return false;
}

//class IRenderableComp
//{
//public:
//    bool operator()(const IRenderable* first, const IRenderable* second)
//    {
//        if (first->GetPriority() < second->GetPriority())
//           return true;
//       return false;
//    }
//};
```

Not super important because I can get it working with vectors, but this little stuff bugs me and I want to understand why.  Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **23.6.4/1** Any sequence container with **random access iterator** and supporting operations `front()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()` can be used to instantiate `priority_queue`.
>
> **23.3.5.1/1** `list` is a sequence container that supports **bidirectional iterators**...

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel dumb.  I even looked in my copy of "The C++ Standard Library - Tutorial and Reference" and apparently completely overlooked that. Thanks